# Variadic class template argument deduction vs. variadic function template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic, template-argument-deduction

How is variadic class template argument deduction different from variadic function template argument deduction? I currently have an event object that creates an object that is a subclass of some base class, and each subclass's constructor takes a non overlapping type and number of arguments. The class I have to accomplish this looks like this

```
template <class T, class... Args>
    struct CreateDrawableObjTreeEvent : RenderEvent {
        CreateDrawableObjTreeEvent(Args&&... args) {
            drawable = new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        T* drawable;
    };
```

The way I would want to instantiate this looks something like this

```
RenderEvent* test = new CreateDrawableObjTreeEvent<DrawableObject>("testvertices");
```

where the DrawableObject constructor takes 1 string. When I try to run this, I run into this error

```
'CreateDrawableObjTreeEvent<DrawableObject>::CreateDrawableObjTreeEvent': no overloaded function takes 1 argument
```

however, when i rework the class structure so that the instantiation happens in a function and not the constructor it compiles without issue

```
    template <class T>
    struct CreateDrawableObjTreeEvent : RenderEvent {
        CreateDrawableObjTreeEvent() {}

        template <class... Args>
        void instantiate(Args&&... args) {
            drawable = new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        T* drawable;
    };

...


CreateDrawableObjTreeEvent<DrawableObject>* test = new CreateDrawableObjTreeEvent<DrawableObject>();
test->instantiate("testvertices");
```

I would really like to be able to use the syntax of the first method, is there any way to achieve this behavior cleanly?

Comment: Is the single ampersand `&` in `Args&... args` a typo? For perfect forwarding, one typically writes `Args&&... args` in order for reference collapsing rules to take effect as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can get

```
RenderEvent* test = new CreateDrawableObjTreeEvent<DrawableObject>("testvertices");
```

to work by moving the varaidic part of the class template to a template for the constrcutor like

```
template <class T>
struct CreateDrawableObjTreeEvent : RenderEvent {
    template <class... Args>
    CreateDrawableObjTreeEvent(Args&&... args) :
        drawable(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))  {}

    T* drawable;
};
```

I should note that as is, the constructor will be called if you try to copy an lvalue of `CreateDrawableObjTreeEvent` since the function that would be generated is a better match.  To stop that you either need to add a constraint to the template, or you could just add a constructor like

```
CreateDrawableObjTreeEvent(CreateDrawableObjTreeEvent& other) : 
    CreateDrawableObjTreeEvent(static_cast<const CreateDrawableObjTreeEvent&>(other)) {}
```

which will be a better match since it is not a template.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++17, so CTAD ([Class Template Argument Deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)) you can deduce also the first template parameter (`T`), passing it trough a some type wrapper.

I mean... suppose you write something as

```
template <typename>
struct wrap_t
 { };

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct CreateDrawableObjectEvent : public RenderEvent
 {
   // ........................VVVVVVVVV
   CreateDrawableObjectEvent (wrap_t<T>, Args && ... args)
      : drawable{ new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...} }
    { }

   std::unique_ptr<T> drawable;
 };
```

you can create `test` passing as follows

```
std::unique_ptr<RenderEvent>
   test { new CreateDrawableObjectEvent{wrap_t<DrawableObject>{}, "testvertices"} };
// .....................................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

simply using the implicit CTAD generated from the `CreateDrawableObjectEvent` constructor.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <memory>

struct RenderEvent
 { };

struct DrawableObject
 {
   template <typename ... Args>
   DrawableObject (Args...)
    { }
 };

template <typename>
struct wrap_t
 { };

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct CreateDrawableObjectEvent : public RenderEvent
 {
   CreateDrawableObjectEvent (wrap_t<T>, Args && ... args)
      : drawable{ new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...} }
    { }

   std::unique_ptr<T> drawable;
 };

int main ()
 {
   std::unique_ptr<RenderEvent>
      test { new CreateDrawableObjectEvent{wrap_t<DrawableObject>{}, "testvertices"} };
 }
```

Unrequested Suggestion: when you directly allocate memory (`new`/`new[]`), please (*please!*) avoid direct management but use smart pointers as `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_prt`/etc.